# AWStats on Plesk consumes all of CPU and crashes server - how do you disable plesk

Tags: awstats

I have Plesk 9.0.1 running on a Red Hat server. Every week or so at about 4:10 AM the server locks up. At this time the server CPU usage shoots from 4% to 90% at the same time as a mass of awstats.pl processes start (I can't see how many as my datat only shows the top 30 processes, but all of these are awstats.pl).

I turned off awstats through the Plesk control panel for all but 5 domains but I still get 90% CPU usage and at least 30 instances of awstats.pl happening at 4:10am as usual.

Does anyone know why this may be? Does anyone know how to disable awstats (I have stats covered using piwik)? Or how do I uninstall awstats without snarling up Plesk?

Comment: Or...uninstall it - I just want to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the file:

- /etc/cron.d/awstats

You need to comment the first line.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

if your are running red-hat like OS (like Fedora or SuSe or RedHat) to remove the package use:

```
rpm -e awstats psa-awstats-configurator
```

If you are running Debian or Ubuntu use

```
dpkg -r awstats psa-awstats-configurator
```

Comment: Thanks James, tried it but I get:
error: Failed dependencies:
        awstats is needed by (installed) psa-9.0.1-cos5.build90090127.18.x86_64

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your crontab to see if somehow it has been entered into there

```
crontab -e
```

Comment: Please we aware that there are lots of other places cron jobs can live. "crontab -e" just shows you the cron jobs for that particular user. There can be anything in /etc/crontab, /etc/cron.*/ or other users (/var/spool/cron/).